# How to delete folders that have n or fewer files in them?

Tags: files, directory, delete, find

I need to do some folder clean-up, and I'd like to remove directories that have 10 or fewer files in them. I tried looking at GNU's `find`, but there wasn't anything related to the number of files in a directory. What commands should I use to accomplish that?

Comment: You need to mention if this is a recursive directory or a flat one. It makes quite a difference. Also if you mean items (also subdirs) or strictly files.

Comment: Could you please include an example in your question to illustrate the problem? I'm not sure I understand all the details.

Comment: __CLOSE_VOTERS__ What you didn't understand from this clear question?

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to use `find`'s `-exec` action to execute a custom test of the number of files.

One could use a second `find` command along with `wc` to find and count files within each directory, but probably a better option would be to shell globbing to slurp the filenames into an array, and then return a logical value indicating whether the size of the array is less than the threshold i.e.

```
files=( dir/* ); ((${#files[@]} < 10))
```

Putting it all together, we should be able to *list* all subdirectories with fewer than 10 files (including sub-subdirectories) using

```
find . -depth -type d ! -name '.' -exec bash -c '
  shopt -s nullglob; files=( "$1"/* ); ((${#files[@]} < ${2:-10}))
  ' bash {} 10 \; -print0 | xargs -0
```

(you can adjust the number `10` after the `bash {}` for different thresholds - the `${2:-10}` parameter expansion makes it default to 10 files if no second argument is given). For example, given

```
$ tree .
.
├── bar
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   ├── file3
│   ├── file4
│   ├── file5
│   ├── file6
│   ├── file7
│   ├── file8
│   ├── file9
│   └── other file
├── baz
│   ├── other file
│   └── subdir
└── foo
    └── somefile

4 directories, 12 files
```

then

```
find . -depth -type d ! -name '.' -exec bash -c '
  shopt -s nullglob; files=( "$1"/* ); ((${#files[@]} < "${2:-10}"))
  ' bash {} 10 \; -print0 | xargs -0
./foo ./baz/subdir ./baz
```

---

If that appears to be doing the right thing you can actually remove them by adding `rm -rf` **but please be very careful with this - remember there is no 'undo'**

```
find . -depth -type d ! -name '.' -exec bash -c '
  shopt -s nullglob; files=( "$1"/* ); ((${#files[@]} < ${2:-10}))
' bash {} 10 \; -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

(The `xargs` could be eliminated by using another `-exec` action to run `rm` more directly, but the formulation above makes it easy to generalize - print, stat, remove or whatever.)

Note this will act recursively i.e. a directory that initially has more than `n` files *including subdirectories* may be removed as a result of some of those subdirectories themselves getting removed as `find` backs up the directory tree - the current directory is explicitly protected from possible deletion by the `! -name '.'` test.

If you **don't** need it to act recursively, you can simply loop over directories and perform the same file count and test logic e.g. to remove all first-level directories containing fewer than 10 files in the current directory

```
shopt -s nullglob
for d in */; do
  files=( "$d"/* )
  ((${#files[@]} < 10)) && echo rm -rf -- "$d"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully test this, but it should work.  You can also use `find` to accomplish this.

```
# Loop over all files
for dir in * **/*; do
    # Make sure this is a directory
    if [ -d "${dir}" ]; then
        # Get the number of files (not including directories) in this directory
        FILE_COUNT=`ls $dir -1 | grep -v / | wc -l`
        # Check if it's less than 10
        if [ $FILE_COUNT -lt 10 ]; then
            # Delete the directory
            rm -rf "${dir}"
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Note that using `wc -l` will give the wrong number if there are newlines in any filenames.